# Building cython with multiple pyx-files on Windows 8 for python 2.7

Tags: python, c, compilation, cython, python-extensions

**To build I use distutils:**

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

**Building a simple `pyx`-file works (setup.py):**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize('test.pyx')
)
```

**Building more than one file (setup.py):**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

# This is the new part...
extensions = [
    Extension('test', ['test.pyx', 'test2.pyx'])
]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```

**test2.pyx:**

```
def say_hello_to2(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

Building the above works fine and I see that both compilation and linking is completed successfully but it doesn't seem like the method `say_hello_to2` is in the binary. Starting python, running the below shows that it's only the methods of `test.pyx`is in the module:

```
>>> import test
>>> dir(test)
['InheritedClass', 'TestClass', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__
', '__package__', '__test__', 'fib', 'fib_no_type', 'primes', 'say_hello_to', 's
in']
>>>
```

Is it possible to add more than one `pyx`-file to the extension build?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple extensions like:

```
extensions = [Extension('test', ['test.pyx']),
              Extension('test2', ['test2.pyx'])]
```